# Weld registry singleton startup when deploying an ear on weblogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: java, weblogic, weld, jboss-weld

I'm deploying an ear, which contains a war file, to Weblogic server 12.2.1.3. Upon deployment of the ear I get the below exception in the logs, blocking deployment:

Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: SingletonProvider is already initialized with org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.RegistrySingletonProvider

I cannot find jar files in the ear/APP-INF/lib and other locations that contain weld-core.jar related classes that might be trying to initialize the the SingletonProvider again.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by stopping and starting weblogic again.